# Fn+Key combinations no longer working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, events

My computer is a Gigabyte P57 laptop which runs Ubuntu 16.04, kernel `4.10.0-041000-generic`. Recently all my hotkeys (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+key) stopped working. This includes mute, volume up, brightness, etc. They were previously working. I am not sure which update caused this. I even upgraded to a newer kernel (stated above) to see if it helps. But nothing has changed.

I used tried `showkey`, `evtest` and `acpi_listen` to check the scan codes or catch any events. Nothing is detected for these key combinations. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You might try checking your bios for something along the lines of "Function Key Behavior". On some laptops, you can change the function key from being a function key to a "multimedia" key and vice versa. Do the function key hot keys (f1-f12) work when you do not press the fn key?

Comment: I thought about the possibility of the function keys being disabled or acting as media keys. However, I can use F5 to refresh my browser, so I guess that is not the problem.